# Asp.Net - Formview - Event Firing - ItemInserted

Tags: asp.net, events, exception, insert, formview

I've a **FormView** with an **insert mode**. I'm throwing an exception in the **ItemInserting Event** which I excpect to catch in the **ItemInserted event** using the **FormViewInsertedEventArgs**, however, the event does not flow from **ItemInserting -> ItemInserted**, instead it breaks inbetween and throws a system exception (the dreadful yellow screen)

Here is my code

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" OnDataBound="FormView1_DataBound"
    OnModeChanging="FormView1_ModeChanging" OnItemInserting="FormView1_ItemInserting"
    RenderOuterTable="false" OnItemInserted="FormView1_ItemInserted"
    DataKeyNames="RoleName">
```

Within this is an InsertItemTemplate with the following Insert LinkButton at the end.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert"/>
```

On click of the "Insert" link button, the code successfuly passes to the following method

```
protected void FormView1_ItemInserting(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
```

But does not enter the

```
protected void FormView1_ItemInserted(object sender, FormViewInsertedEventArgs e)
```

with or without exception.

I'm using a List to locally store the data, from which my static methods update the SQL database.

Comment: Why are you throwing an exception? Do you want to cancel the insertion  of the item?

Comment: Yes, for example, I validate and findout the length of the input exceeds the permisable value, then I throw a new ValidationException(), ofcourse, I can simply handle it using condition checking but the actual problem is when I have an SQL Exception.